# WPF, Вопрос по ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Предположим у меня есть 2 ComboBox`a. Как сделать так, что бы второй бокс становился активным(по дефолту у него IsEnabled="False")  в случае выбора какой либо позиции из первого бокса прямо в XAML.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Box2"
          Width="300"
          Cursor="Hand"
          Focusable="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AllowedReportTypes,
                                Converter={StaticResource ReportTypeEnumConverter}}"
          SelectedValuePath="Value" IsEnabled="False">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Description}"
                TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Либо как присвоить IsEnabled="True" ему из кода? (Интересует синтаксис)

Comment: Подпишитесь на `SelectionChanged` и добавьте туда что-то типа `Box2.IsEnabled = Box1.SelectionIndex > -1`

Comment: Андрей, спасибо большое)

Comment: @Андрей: Почему не как ответ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если говорить о XAML-решениях, вы можете это сделать через конвертер или триггер. Например, через триггер будет так:

```
<ComboBox Name="Box1" ...>
    ...
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="Box2" ...> <!-- IsEnabled не прописываем -->
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Box1}"
                             Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
    ...
</ComboBox>
```

[image: анимашка]

Comment: Круто, спасибо большое) Как раз изначально хотел через триггеры сделать, но не получалось.

Comment: @MrStacky: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!